# How correct update version gem mailcatcher in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailcatcher

1. I installed gem mailcatcher v. 0.5.12,

2.run bundle exec mailcatcher.

But no i want update to version 0.6.

I do next:

1. gem uninstall mailcatcher v. 0.5.12
2. gem install mailcatcher 0.6...

I run command bundle show and display error: **Could not find mailcatcher-0.5.12 in any of the sources**

How me correct remove version 0.5.12?

Comment: You need to specify the required compatible version in your `Gemfile` and then run `bundle update mailcatcher`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the required compatible version of `mailcatcher` in your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'mailcatcher', '~> x.x.x'
```

Then run

```
bundle update mailcatcher
```